# A natural langage processing tool that can tokenize a stream of punctuationless words into sentences?

Tags: gratis, language

Assuming I want to take a bunch of punctuationless words like this (It commes from the "whisper" AI model foor speech-to-text), and I want to improve its legibilty by adding puctuation.

(Note that *it was me* who has manually inserted basic punctuation and capitalization in lines 1, 2)

> Part 1 unit 5 the language of spoken commentary. Extracts from a football commentary. this is BBC radio 4. were now taking you over to hybris stadium for a commentary on the football league match between arsenal and Wolverhampton wanderers your commentator this afternoon is James cooper and this is James cooper welcoming listeners on this bright sunny rather mild mid December afternoon to hybris stadium where a capacity crowd are waiting to see how arsenal who are third in the table face up to wolves at home wolves youll remember drew with arsenal one all in the away match at mollyn earlier in the season but theyve been playing very well lately and arsenal will have to be on top form if theyre to keep their unbeaten home record intact ...

Also does that tool have an "autofix" or "fix all" feature, and does not insist onmanually confirming all proposed changes - like most spellcheckers do? It should just take the whole text and insert punctuation for the entirety of the text.

To demonstrate a good result, I have just  used OpenAIs [grammar correction](https://beta.openai.com/playground/p/default-grammar?model=text-davinci-003) ( a pay-as-you-go service) and it turned the sample text into this paragraph, **properly tokenized**:

> Part 1, Unit 5: The Language of Spoken Commentary. Extracts from a football commentary. This is BBC Radio 4. We're now taking you over to Hybris Stadium for a commentary on the football league match between Arsenal and Wolverhampton Wanderers. Your commentator this afternoon is James Cooper and this is James Cooper welcoming listeners on this bright, sunny, rather mild mid-December afternoon to Hybris Stadium, where a capacity crowd are waiting to see how Arsenal, who are third in the table, face up to Wolves at home. Wolves, you'll remember, drew with Arsenal one-all in the away match at Mollyn earlier in the season, but they've been playing very well lately and Arsenal will have to be on top form if they're to keep their unbeaten home record intact...

This is what I want, but I'd prefer a desktop-based tool. Compiling and building is fine for me.
It can be an desktop app, or a free tier of a freemium webservice accessed from the desktop.

Meanwhile, I have installed the free Java-based variant of LanguageTool.org . This app runs on my desktop, but it just highlights misspelled words  and does not  recognize sentences. Thus it leaves a lot of work to be done.
I